# Why does Google offer so many client libs? Which should I use for Stackdriver logging?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to send logs to Stackdriver and am a little confounded by the option of two dependencies I could use —

The [Google Cloud Client Library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.35.0/index.html) recommends google-cloud version 0.35.0-alpha

The [logging docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) recommend I install google-cloud-logging version 1.14.0

Googling around for the [LogEntryOperation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/logging/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/logging/v2/model/LogEntryOperation.html) I would like to use [yields](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-logging/v2-rev577-1.23.0) a google-api-services-logging version v2-rev577-1.23.0.

Are the underlying communications mechanisms to Google's API different between these?

Which of these is most feature-full, least likely to be deprecated, and maintained going forward? Why are there so many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud ships two kinds of client libraries:

1. Auto generated libraries that just export the REST API directly. These are called the "Google API Client Libraries". These have the advantage that they cover every API in every language in complete detail.

   For Java, these are in `com.google.apis`. This is what you found searching for LogEntryOperation.
2. Hand-crafted libraries that aim to be more "natural". These are called the "Google Cloud APIs". These are easier to use and fit in better with how the language is used. However they are available for fewer API/language combinations, and don't always cover 100% of the API.

   For Java, these are in `com.google.cloud`. This is what our docs recommend. `google-cloud` is simply a convenience package for all of the available libraries, including the logging-specific `google-cloud-logging` package.

The logging library is a good example of the difference. As the actual REST API exposes a [LogEntryOperation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogEntryOperation) resource, the auto-generated API just creates a [LogEntryOperation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/logging/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/logging/v2/model/LogEntryOperation.html) class that blindly copies this.

By contrast, the manually created API has a more concisely named [Operation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.35.0/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/logging/Operation.html) class. In addition, the manually created API provides a better static constructor, a Builder, and names the `first()` and `last()` methods more sensibly.

Comment: Thanks. Is it reasonable to expect all of them to be maintained reasonably quickly and thoroughly, or does the manually created API ever lag behind in features?

Comment: The manually created APIs are pretty good about updates, but not perfect. If you use alpha or beta features you're quite likely to find unimplemented bits. Of course they are [open source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node), so you could contribute new features yourself ;) The team is pretty responsive on GitHub issues too.

Comment: @David what about the [GAE libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/)?

Comment: Those are not client libraries for other cloud products. They are libraries for features within GAE. They are slow moving, but that's because GAE is not adding new features like those any more, not because they are out of date.